# I don't have cortana, how can I activate it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cortana

I only have "search in windows" option and I don't see any configuration to activate cortana:

[image]

I've seen that a lot of people have problems with their region, but that doesn't seem to be my problem, I don't even get that message.
How can I activate cortana? I used to have it. I don't know if it dissapeared with some kind of update or maybe I stopped some kind of service...
How can I activate it?

Edit: I know it's only available in some regions and countries, but I also know it is available in Spain. The only part important there is that on the left pic it says "Search in Windows" instead of something related with cortana and on the right pic I have no options to modify anything cortana's related.^

I'm using Windows 10 Education 1607

Comment: Cortana only is available for certain regions and languages.  Have you confirmed Cortana is available for your language and region.  Update your question to include that information.  A screenshot without an English translation isn't very helpful.

Comment: [How do I start Cortana?](http://superuser.com/questions/1086354/how-do-i-start-cortana?rq=1).  After you merge your accounts, and update your question, also include the Windows 10 version (1607, 1511, 1703) your using.  Wait until you have merged your accounts before you reply to this RFI

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.  For reference, the question was posted using http://superuser.com/users/687799/delin and the edit was proposed using http://superuser.com/users/687808/delinage

Comment: @StephenRauch, it looks like this might be a separate issue from 1607 in general.  The Edu version purposely excludes Cortana.  It isn't clear, though, whether it can be added via a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Cortana is not available in the EDU version of Win 10
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4vnt7y/cortana_officially_removed_from_windows_10/

Answer (score 0):

Install windows updates.  Early Windows 10 shows the search box but after a couple updates that changes to cortana.
Do this by going into the [Settings] and then selecting [Update & Security]  Then click [Check for updates]

Answer (score 0):

On build 1607 the most common solution is by using the command

```
Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"} .
```

this powershell command worked for me.